# Question regarding the laws of Brachos

Tags: halacha, blessing, grapes-wine, water, birkat-meeyn-shalosh

If one drank half a Revi’is of wine, and then drank a Revi’is of water, and then recited “Borei Nefashos”, with the intention of drinking another half a Revi’is of wine afterwards, should he recite “Al Hagefen after he drinks the second half of the Revi’is, or does the “Borei Nefashos” cover the first half that he drank before he recited it, being that half a Revi’is of wine can be “Mitztaref” to half a Revi’is of water, for making a “Borei Nefashos”?

Comment: "being that half a Revi’is of wine can be “Mitztaref” to half a Revi’is of water, to make a “Borei Nefashos”" How do you know this?

Comment: So it would seem from MB 210:1